# ¿Para los argentinos y uruguayos, qué es "hacer un rebaje" en relación a la conducción de un auto?

Tags: coloquialismos, argentina, uruguay

En Argentina, "hacer un rebaje" implica usar el embrague o simplemente es hacer una marcha descendente y tu vez si tu práctica te permite prescindir o no de él, digo, porque si no lo haces a las rpm justas puedes afectar la vida útil de la caja a no ser que tengas una caja sincronizada o bloquear la rueda trasera si encuentras que la relación entre una marcha y otra es muy larga cuando haces el cambio pero es peligroso no usar el embrague si es que a esto se refieren con hacer rebajes. Posiblemente un experto piloto lo usaría para reducir levemente la velocidad o para reducirla más rápido sin usar el freno, pero no en el día a día o si se le rompe el cable de embrague.

> Senna tuvo que frenar con el freno porque no podía hacer marchas descendentes en la zona trabada, no podía **hacer rebajes**, porque la caja estaba trabada en la sexta marcha, pero igual ganó GP de Brazil, autódromo de Interlagos, São Paulo.

> El mayor problema con los **rebajes** es que cuando los haces estás frenando o reduciendo la velocidad, así que es difícil hacerlo a las rpm justas para eso está el embrague, igual creo que estaría bueno tomarse un buen tiempo para conocer la caja para no afectar su vida útil como la conducción mejora. Por ahora no probé subir marchas sin embrague pero sí bajar, aunque de 3ª a 2ª y 2ª a 1ª me gusta usarlo para suavizar.

> Al **rebajar** sin embraguar corres el riesgo de bloquear la rueda trasera con la posibilidad que la moto se te cruce, ni hablar si estás ligeramente inclinado, la otra es forzar o joder la caja si le errás, porque en realidad para rebajar embragás y aceleras un poco para equiparar las vueltas del motor a las de la caja, y eso ya de por sí lleva un tiempo conserguirlo para no pasarte o quedarte corto.

> Todo **rebaje** mal hecho redunda 100% en la vida útil remanente del motor, más encima si no usan un aceite adecuado.

> ¿Para qué frenar con el motor??? Simplemente para que las pastillas, disco y tambor te duren un poco más. También es muy recomendable hacerlo en el auto, y en todo lo que ande a motor, supongo! Otro motivo para **hacer rebajes** es que no se caiga de vueltas tan innecesariamente. Imagínate que querés aflojar levemente la velocidad, no vas a andar embragando para frenar levemente con los frenos, ¿no? Porque después tenés que volver a engranar la marcha, y que el motor vuelva a tomar vueltas, pero la verdad que no tiene sentido. Además te va a gastar más nafta. Mejor, en cambio, levemente soltás el acelerador y vas dejando que solo se frene, sin perder vueltas y ¡Sin tener que vover a acoplar el cambio!!

La pregunta es: ¿Qué entienden los argentinos por **rebaje o hacer rebajes** en relación al automovilismo, manejo o conducción?

---

@karloswitt
¿Y cuál es la pregunta? No encuentro la relación con el lenguaje; más bien con cuestiones de automoción y mecánica, ¿no? –

> rebaje. Arg. y Ur. Disminución de la marcha de un automóvil por medio de un cambio a una velocidad más corta.

Comment: ¿Y cuál es la pregunta? No encuentro la relación con el lenguaje; más bien con cuestiones de automoción y mecánica, ¿no?

Comment: Creo que la razón por la que esta pregunta ha sido cerrada es porque no está claro cuál es la pregunta. No hay ningún signo de interrogación, y la primera frase es tan larga que no queda claro si es informativa o interrogativa. Quizá si editas la publicación para aclarar cuál es la pregunta, esta vuelve a ser abierta.

Comment: @wimi Porque para mí "si es que" es una forma de plantear la duda también, como en "si es que a esto se refieren con hacer rebajes."

Comment: Bueno, entiendo que hay una gran diferencia al comparar la difusión e historia del automovilismo en argentina con la de otros países, porque "hacer rebajes" lo dice gente de calle, periodistas y mecánicos, y en otros sólo se vela por el limitado pero correcto uso del lenguaje y ya tengo la respuesta más o menos resuelta. Saludos.

Comment: @karloswitt "rebaje. Arg. y Ur. Disminución de la marcha de un automóvil por medio de un cambio a una velocidad más corta". Todavía no entiendo tu argumentación.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según el Diccionario de la Lengua española:

> **rebaje**. Arg. y Ur. Disminución de la marcha de un automóvil por medio de un cambio a una velocidad más corta.

Comment: A eso me refería, que incluso está en el vocabulario automovilístico, entonces por qué cerrarlo? También me preguntaba si sólo a eso se refieren arg. y uy. desde su perspectiva digamos local y técnica.

Comment: Yo también lo entendí así. Por todas estas cuestiones ---incluyendo dichas perspectivas--- doy un voto a la pregunta, que entiendo es pertinente.

De hecho, una de las cuestiones que me llama la atención de esta comunidad es precisamente la llamada de atención sobre muchos detalles que nos pasan desapercibidos... hasta que alguien nos lo resalta. Que es tu caso, por ejemplo. De modo que te doy las gracias por ello, ya que he aprendido nuevos conceptos, antes de tu pregunta no conocía.